# Why is my triplet object being destroyed?

Tags: c++, oop, queue

Hello I have this code

```
class Triplets
{
public:
int nVal1;
int nVal2;
NodeT *ptrNode;
bool bUpdate;

Triplets()
{
    cout << "creating empty triplet" << endl;
    nVal2 = 0;
    nVal1 = 0;
    bUpdate = false;
    ptrNode = NULL;
}

~Triplets()
{
    cout << "destroying triplet" << endl;
    delete ptrNode;
}

Triplets(int nVal1, int nVal2, bool bUpdate, NodeT *ptrNode)
{
    cout << "creating triple with values" << endl;
    this->nVal2 = nVal2;
    this->nVal1 = nVal1;
    this->bUpdate = bUpdate;
    this->ptrNode = ptrNode;
}
 };
```

This usage

```
void find_triplets(NodeT *ptrRoot)
{


   if (ptrRoot != NULL)
    {
    find_triplets(ptrRoot->left);
    find_triplets(ptrRoot->right);


    cout << "find triplets and save them to the queue" << endl;
        cout << " we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys" << endl;

     if(ptrRoot->left != NULL && ptrRoot->right != NULL)
        {

        if (ptrRoot->left->done == true && ptrRoot->right->done == true)
        {
        cout << "we got one of 2 sons true so do something, this are the sons "<< ptrRoot->left->key_value << " " << ptrRoot->right->key_value << endl;         

        cout << "sum them and put it in the father and set it to true " << endl;
        ptrRoot->key_value = ptrRoot->left->key_value + ptrRoot->right->key_value;
        ptrRoot->done = true;


        cout << "thread queue " << endl;
        Triplets triplet(ptrRoot->left->key_value, ptrRoot->right->key_value, ptrRoot->done, ptrRoot);
        qThreads.push(triplet);
       }
     }
     }
    }
```

And this main

```
MyThread mt;
mt.start();
mt.run();
cout << "sum = " << mt.sum(&bt) << endl;
THREADS_HOW_MANY = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
std::cout << THREADS_HOW_MANY << std::endl;

while (!bt.Values_to_do.empty())
{
    cout << "da vals to sum are these " << bt.Values_to_do.front() << " and aready done " << bt.values_done.front() << endl;
    bt.Values_to_do.pop();
    bt.values_done.pop();
}

  while(!mt.qThreads.empty())
{
cout << "da triplet are " << mt.qThreads.front().nVal1 << " " <<mt.qThreads.front().nVal2 << " "
        << mt.qThreads.front().ptrNode << " " << mt.qThreads.front().bUpdate
        << endl;
mt.qThreads.pop();

}
```

All of this give me this result(obviously wrong)

```
  done lets chek
  find triplets
  find triplets and save them to the queue
   we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
   find triplets and save them to the queue
    we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
 find triplets and save them to the queue
 we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
 we got one of 2 sons true so do something, this are the sons 2 8
 sum them and put it in the father and set it to true 
 thread queue 
 creating triple with values
 destroying triplet
 find triplets and save them to the queue
 we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
 find triplets and save them to the queue
 we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
find triplets and save them to the queue
we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
 we got one of 2 sons true so do something, this are the sons 11 15
 sum them and put it in the father and set it to true 
thread queue 
creating triple with values
destroying triplet
find triplets and save them to the queue
 we hit a hot spot is null the root, nothing to see here move along boys
 we got one of 2 sons true so do something, this are the sons 19976608 19976464
 sum them and put it in 
 the father and set it to true 
 thread queue 
 creating triple with values
 destroying triplet
 the gran total is 19976320
```

Now my q is why is my triplet object no being added to the queue and is being destroyed instead, that is what is causing the sum to come out all messed up. Thanks.

Comment: To me, looking at your code, it is not clear what you want to achieve, so it is not clear what should be changed.  However, general memory management, deleting a node without taking it out of the tree and only acting when both left and right are not null seems like issues to me.

Comment: I'm not doing that the tree class takes care of that, is to long to place it here this class is the triplets that have 2 sons with numbers and a pointer to the father to store the sum. So what I want to do is store them in the queue the actual object to be able to modify it at will.

Comment: But the node is deleted in your Triplet destructor and you make a new Triplet with the pointer to a Node, you then push a copy on the queue and let the new Triplet be destroyed when leaving the scope, which deletes the Node without being taken from the tree.

Comment: If the Triplet is not responsible for the lifetime of the Node, then it shouldn't delete the node pointer in the destructor.  But becasue of the limited code, this is very unclear.

Comment: ok now I think I'm getting it, is there a way to use it like java with pointers? I mean to point to where I need to store the value, w/o having to handle the mess that pointers does in this code

Comment: std::shared_ptr/boost::shared_ptr comes probably close to what you want.  Just be sure to understand them before usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tl;dr - what pops up is that you have a destructor that manages memory:

```
~Triplets()
{
    cout << "destroying triplet" << endl;
    delete ptrNode;
}
```

yet no copy constructor and assignment operator. Try implementing those.

Comment: @user1423656 to obey the rule of three.

Comment: @user1423656 see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: In this case, the rule of 3 isn't even enough: the pointer is copied in the constructor and then deleted in the destructor.

Comment: @stefaanv that's what the rule of 3 means - making a deep copy.

Comment: That won't help if he's passing the pointer to the normal constructor (I wrote constructor, not copy constructor)

Comment: I'm trying to implement those and this is giving me no matching function for call to ‘Triplets::Triplets(const Triplets&)’ I have it like so Triplets( Triplets &t)
    {
        cout << "creating a copy triplets with the copy const" <<     endl;
        form_triplet(t.nVal1, t.nVal2, t.bUpdate, t.ptrNode);
    }

Comment: ok that seem to have worked now the program is going crazy with tree deletion is calling 1000's of times the destructor of tree, I'll put an other q

Answer (score 1):

You seem to create copies of the `Triplets` class:

```
Triplets triplet(ptrRoot->left->key_value, ptrRoot->right->key_value, ptrRoot->done, ptrRoot);
qThreads.push(triplet);
```

Depending on the declaration of `qThreads`, you first create an instance of `Triplets` named `triplet`, then when you push it into `qThreads` it's copied. Then when the scope leaves (at the next `}`) the `triplet` instance is destroyed. This will of course mean that you `delete` the pointer inside it and the pointer the copy has will now be invalid.

The solution is to follow [the rules of three, five or zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: yea I'm creating or more like want to create several objects and add them to the queue. qThreads is this  queue<Triplets> qThreads; I don't want a copy how do I tell it that I want that object in the queue not a copy.

Comment: @user1423656 You are putting a _copy_ in the queue and the _original_ is destroyed. Think about what that will do with e.g. your pointer.

Comment: so If I want the object to go in the queue not some copy, create a new object triplet and add that to the queue.

Comment: @user1423656 No, the solution is in Luchians answer and comments.